# Conflict between linux kernel and nvme drives. Faulty power saving mode enabled? ("nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 pcie_aspm=off" didn't help)

Tags: linux-kernel, disk, hardware, proxmox, nvme

I have two barely identical servers. Both with:

1. BIOSTAR GTA690 motherboard
2. Intel CPU
3. Same amount of RAM & disk layout
4. PVE distribution (debian based hypervisor). Kernel 5.19.17-1-pve.

I have bought 3 Seagate Firecuda 530 (2TB) for each one. The six drives are failing in the same way in the two servers and I don't know why.

Before anything, I tried to upgrade NVMe SSDs firmware, but when I was going to download it I saw that it was the same version as the installed one (SU6SM003, release date 01-Mar-22). So I take for granted they are updated to the most recent version.

Also, the drives are completely unformatted and "empty", and I was doing raw fio tests on them to test performance when I saw they are failing.

They fail with any kind of test mode (read, write, randread and ranwrite). Two of the drives are connected to a gen4 m2 connector, the other one to a gen3. The gen 3 drive seems to survive a longer bench time even when the pcie gen3 isn't bottle-necking the data transmission. I have monitored the temperature during the benchs and I have never seen it reach 60 ºC. Warning temperature and critical temperatures are 90 & 95 ºC, so even if I'm using the default motherboard heatsinks for them, I think it's not a temperature problem.

Here I attach a `kernel.log` sample of the `nvme0` failure:

```
Feb 17 10:42:58 pve-02 kernel: [   63.521693] pcieport 0000:00:06.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:06.0
Feb 17 10:42:58 pve-02 kernel: [   63.521703] pcieport 0000:00:06.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Feb 17 10:42:58 pve-02 kernel: [   63.521704] pcieport 0000:00:06.0:   device [8086:464d] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Feb 17 10:42:58 pve-02 kernel: [   63.521706] pcieport 0000:00:06.0:    [ 0] RxErr
Feb 17 10:43:29 pve-02 kernel: [   95.188263] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0xffffffff, PCI_STATUS=0x10
Feb 17 10:43:29 pve-02 kernel: [   95.188269] nvme nvme0: Does your device have a faulty power saving mode enabled?
Feb 17 10:43:29 pve-02 kernel: [   95.188270] nvme nvme0: Try "nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 pcie_aspm=off" and report a bug
Feb 17 10:43:29 pve-02 kernel: [   95.244775] nvme 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Feb 17 10:43:29 pve-02 kernel: [   95.244881] nvme nvme0: Removing after probe failure status: -19
Feb 17 10:43:29 pve-02 kernel: [   95.268964] nvme0n1: detected capacity change from 3907029168 to 0
```

It's the same for `nvme1` and `nvme2`. And it's the same on both servers.

I have tried to set `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 pcie_aspm=off` as the kernel log suggests. I'm using systemd-boot so I added it to the options line in the `/boot/efi/loader/entries/proxmox-5.19.17-1-pve.conf` file. After restart `nvme get-feature /dev/nvme0 -f 0x0c -H` returns:

```
get-feature:0xc (Autonomous Power State Transition), Current value:00000000
    Autonomous Power State Transition Enable (APSTE): Disabled
```

Before it was enabled so I was hoping now the error would be solved, but it isn't. Drives continue to fail but now log is slightly different:

```
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.637355] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0xffffffff, PCI_STATUS=0x10
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.637377] nvme nvme0: Does your device have a faulty power saving mode enabled?
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.637384] nvme nvme0: Try "nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 pcie_aspm=off" and report a bug
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.694007] nvme0: Admin Cmd(0x6), I/O Error (sct 0x3 / sc 0x71)
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.733561] nvme 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.733671] nvme nvme0: Removing after probe failure status: -19
Feb 20 10:50:38 pve-02 kernel: [ 1117.761606] nvme0n1: detected capacity change from 3907029168 to 0
```

The pcieport error has disappeared but now there is this new concept: `Admin Cmd(0x6), I/O Error (sct 0x3 / sc 0x71)`, that god knows what does it means.

Here I attach the smart data of nvme0 on server 2:

```
root@pve-02:~# smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.19.17-1-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Seagate FireCuda 530 ZP2000GM30013
Serial Number:                      7VR033KY
Firmware Version:                   SU6SM003
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1bb1
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x6479a7
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      1
NVMe Version:                       1.4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            6479a7 6d3f00fdd1
Local Time is:                      Mon Feb 20 11:46:09 2023 CET
Firmware Updates (0x18):            4 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005d):     Comp DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x08):         Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     90 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     95 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.80W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     2.90W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0250W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2500    7500
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4    10500   65000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        28 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          5%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    9,323,369 [4.77 TB]
Data Units Written:                 2,755,621 [1.41 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 125,896,434
Host Write Commands:                271,550,259
Controller Busy Time:               26
Power Cycles:                       2,348
Power On Hours:                     287
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   2,312
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      88
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 63 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0         88     0  0x0008  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -
  1         87     0  0x1014  0x4004      -            0     0     -
```

I don't know what to do next, I feel like in a dead end, so any help would be helpful.

As a kind of appendix I'm going to write here a more extended description of the fio test that I have done, just in case is useful for someone.

First of all I was testing in 4k randwrite mode, trying to bench the writting maximum IOPS of the drives. Even if the three disks were giving 400k IOPS (initially, they were decreasing slowly over time) the gen 3 disk lasted long. I have repeated this more than once and it was always the same and I don't understand why if the performance was the same for all the three disks.

Then I reduced the output setting iodepth and jobs to 1. In this way IOPS started at 140k IOPS. In this mode gen4 drives failed too (at 56 and 57 ºC) but gen3 drive ran for 4h without error. Of course gen3 & gen4 drives were having same BW & IOPS.

Then I switched to max 4k IOPS. 1M IOPS for gen4, 700k on gen3. Gen4 drives were obliterated in seconds, gen3 in two minutes at most. Temperatures never exceeded 55 degrees.

Finally I switched to max 4M sequential read. 1700 IOPS for gen4, 850 for gen3. b. Here first crashed a gen4, then a gen3 and lastly the other gen4. In fact this last was the most different one, lasting between 15 and 20 minutes.

Then I gave up because none of this was making sense to me, so any help it's welcome.

Comment: Hello @Héctor. Any updates from your end? Have you tried repeating the tests on the latest linux kernel? Note that in my case I am dealing with two NVME slots on my X570 motherboard and only one of them is hosting a very fast Gen4 M.2 SSD properly (w/o errors), while the other NVME physical slot, being slightly elevated from the Motherboard itself via an extension cable (something I cannot change), works fine when I do not stress it out, but consistently fails if I run 'fio' or 'stress-ng --hdd 64' on it. I interpret the failure as being of HW nature (NVME extension cables).